# You do not have permission to access this device : Samsung Galaxy Mega USB connection with Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, usb, permissions, android

I have connected my Samsung Galaxy Mega phone to Windows 7 laptop. I could see my phone icon in 'My Computer' window.

When I click on the phone icon, it displays "You do not have permission to access this device".

**What I have tried?**

★ Phone → Settings → USB computer Connections → Media device → checked ☑

★ Phone → Settings → More → Developer Options → USB debugging → checked ☑

★ Laptop → Group policy editor → Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System → Removable storage access → "Removable Disks: Deny read access" → disabled.

★ Laptop → Group policy editor → Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System → Removable storage access → "All Removable Storage classes: Deny all access" → disabled.

**Testing of the above settings:**

1. I have connected the external portable hard disk to my laptop. I can access all my files from the hard disk.
2. I have connected my mobile to my laptop → "You do not have permission to access this device."
3. I have connected my mobile to a different desktop. I am able to access phone media.
4. I have installed Samsung Kies. Even this application is not able to access the mobile.

**My Question:**

How can access this Samsung mobile from my laptop?

**Note:**

I have admin access on my Windows 7 laptop.

My mobile uses Android version 4.3.

Kernel version 3.4.0-2493474

SE for Android status: Permissive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check, the phone appears under portable devices. So in group policy editor you should disable **WPD Devices** under **Removable storage access**.

Laptop → Group policy editor → Computer configuration → Administrative templates → System → Removable storage access → "WPD Device: Deny read access" → disabled

Laptop → Group policy editor → Computer configuration → Administrative templates → System → Removable storage access → "WPD Device: Deny write access" → disabled